# How is ではいけませんか used in this sentence?

Tags: negation, questions, particle-か

[image]

My understanding is that the sentence was reverse so it's

あなたと私の出会いのように運命だから、(thought it may be wrong)

However I'm not sure how to take ではいけませんか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xでいける means "X will do/pass/suffice".

- この作戦でいける。
  This strategy will do.
- それではいけない。
  That won't do.

で is a method/means marker, and いける is the potential form of 行く ("to go").

And here X is a sentence "(それは)運命だから(だ)", which is functioning as a noun phrase.

> 運命だから(だ)、ではいけませんか？
>
> "It's because it's destiny" — won't this do?
> Isn't it enough to say "because it was destined"?